# repeated items in a list python

Tags: python, list

I have a huge dictionary (like a database) where I want to find some specific information. Let's call the huge database A. 
If one specific number of a new list is inside A I want to print some info. This is what I am doing (oversimplified):

```
    A = {info1:34, info2:4, info3:-34, info4:2,.......}
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]

    for i,j in A.iteritems():
      if j in b:
        print b, i
```

It seems like is working, but after a better look into the results I realized that the code only prints the first coincidence that it found. How could I change it to get all the coincidence in my database.

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: This code shouldn't work at all -- `if b in i` would raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand what you are trying is overkill. This is a solution that makes use of the fact that `dict` is actually a [*hash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table):

```
for item in b:
    if item in A:
        print A[item]
```

**EDIT**: from your edit it seems that the keys and values are interchanged. Why are you doing this? Maybe it's a better idea to switch them, so that my above solution works (it's *much* more efficient, and you only have to do the switch once). If you need multiple identical keys, you can use a `MultiDict`, like `paste.util.multidict.Multidict`, installable by `pip install paste`

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "I realized that the code only prints the first coincidence that it found", it sounds like you are expecting your code to return multiple matches for the same key. Python's [dict](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) has unique keys, so that isn't possible (and wouldn't really make sense). If you try to store multiple values using the same key, you'll just clobber previous values.